# Is there any Wordpress theme for Self Storagae just like Spacer

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am working on Self Storage website which is as same as Spacer (https://www.spacer.com.au). Is there any wordpress theme just like spacer where I can also list my places and integrate with google search or advance search.
Feel free to ask in case of any query.
Thanks;

Comment: Asking for product recommendation is considered off-the-topic for this forum. There is nothing really special about the site that you are referring to. It is just a so-called single-page website that you can either build it using Wordpress yourself, or download (if it is a free theme)/purchase (if it is a premium theme) a ready-made single page theme and modify it.

Comment: Thank you @hcheung. The main thing in Spacer is the advance search check the below link:
https://www.spacer.com.au/search?transactable_type_id=438&category_ids=4601,4604&per_page=50&sort=custom_attributes.space_availability_asc,distance_asc&sort=

How can I do this?

Comment: I google on "geo search engine wordpress", I saw something similar that you might want to take a look.